# Red language executable also opening up a console

Tags: user-interface, console, rebol, red

I compiled an executable using following simple code (from Red language websites) in Red language:

```
Red [title: "test" needs: 'view]
view [
    below
    button
    field
    text "Red is really pretty easy to program."
    text-list
    check
]
```

I used following command:

```
red -c myprog.red
```

It was created without any error. However, when I run it there are 2 problems:

1. The application window does not have the title given above ("test").
2. A console window also opens that closes only after the application is shut down. It will be better if such a window does not open at all and only application window opens.

I am working on Windows-7. Where is the problem and how can these be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should split your `1. No title` into a separate question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
red -c -t Windows myprog.red
```

and the compilat is specifically for Windows

Comment: @rgchris and mso I was mistaken that it was also to be found on the Red github page. What is the <rebol> tag for?

Comment: The reason I thought it was easy to find and on the Red github Readme page is that I have it mentioned on my Red project on Xiangqi, "Chinese Chess" here https://github.com/iArnold/Xiangqi. Sorry for the confusion.